# Atlas/Layer: how to set LYRMessageOptionsPushNotificationConfigurationKey when subclassing ATLConversationViewController

Tags: ios9

I subclass the `ATLConversationViewController`, now I only get silent push notifications when a message is sent.

How can I set the `LYRMessageOptionsPushNotificationConfigurationKey` when subclassing `ATLConversationViewController`?